# iphone/ipad web video only plays over 3g not Wifi

Tags: ios, apache, html5-video

Wonder if anyone can help here. On my website, I have a video on the front page, which has been set up with the HTML 5 video tag. The video performs correctly with the standard range of browsers - BUT

My iPad and iPhone show the video with a slash through the play button.

O.K. - I thought, I must have messed up the encoding of the MP4 file, so I re-encoded it several times, but it still won't play.

Then it started working on my iPhone - but I noticed my Wifi connection had dropped and it was playing it through a 3G connection. I thought I'd cracked it - but when I connect via WiFi it does't play.

Just to check I got a few friends with iPads/iPhones to check, and when connected over 3g on an iPhone the video works. (I don't know anyone with iPad with 3g). With iPhone or iPad over Wifi it doesn't.

I'm thinking it may be a server configuration issue (apache) but I'm struggling here.

The video is embedded with the HTML5 video tag as below:

```
<div align="center">
   <video width="688px" height="384px" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls"poster="media/video/lvposter.jpg">
       <source src="media/video/livingdisplayvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
       <source src="media/video/livingdisplayvideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
       <source src="media/video/livingdisplayvideo.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
   </video>
</div>
```

It is in a joomla site in a module position, but since it works over 3g, I don't think that this is causing the issue. The site is [www.livingdisplay.com](http://www.livingdisplay.com)

Can anyone save my sanity, as I really don't know where to start looking to resolve this ?

Comment: I have the same issue here, no solution at the moment.
But here is a clue, my colleague find it may be a security issue.
When the wifi is open to public, the video won't play.However, When wifi is changed to WPA/WPA2 with password, it plays.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my iphone suddenly stopped playing video on my router's wifi, but worked when I connected to my neighbor's open wifi.  All other internet activity continued to work.  Then all internet traffic failed, but I could still access other machines on my local network.

I tried the following:

1. Set up Fiddler to use as a proxy on another machine on my network.  Web pages would load, but requests for video files never showed up in Fiddler.  The router received them and refused to forward them to the Fiddler machine.  So this didn't solve the problem
2. Removed and recreated my wifi (no difference)
3. Reset all settings on my iphone, using the settings panels.  (no difference)
4. Reset my router (no difference)
5. Performed a factory reset on my router (no difference)
6. Used another router (solved the issue)
7. Upgraded to IOS5 and performed a factory reset on my ipod (then it worked with the first router)

I never did find the cause, but hopefully points 6 or 7 can be used for others that have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Change DNS settings for your iPhone and iPad wifi.
You may note your existing settings for future use if needed.
But as of now can put - 8.8.8.8.

It worked for me when I encountered similar problem. Same applied to both devices by me.

Comment: You should explain what `8.8.8.8` means within your solution. It's Google's Public DNS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS 

So you're rerouting **all** your Internet traffic domain data over their servers.