# captive portal for OSX can't play streaming or mp4

Tags: html, macos, video

We are using Wifi Hotspot and implementing video ads.
 The problem of OSX is when I use my Macbook Air connected to Wifi, the captive portal  and content popup appear. I just use HTML5 or HLS to make a player for streaming a videos

Also, I made a lot of test cases and failed. Here are some things that failed:

1. Use Streaming Server ( Already open the wall garden to stream  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/vod/mp4:myfile.mp4/playlist.m3u8 )
2. DirectLink to the files of mp4

After I use the tools to see the package running such as wireshark, the package is still stuck on the captive portal.

How can I make a stream play on popup of the captive portal???

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, not only on Mac OS X but also on iOS devices. I also found a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390395/iphone-ipad-web-video-only-plays-over-3g-not-wifi. I noticed on the iOS devices, that the video plays well if there is a 3G connection, also inside the captive portal! This is very strange behavior.

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap, how do you open captive portal when your device connect to 3G network?

Comment: @Indiana it was a strange behavior: some devices can have both, wifi and 3G network at the same time. So you might experience the following behavior (e.g. captured with wireshark/server logging): The captive portal open up due to recognition of limited internet availability, inside the captive portal browser, but inside the captive portal browser some files are loaded over 3G connection. I don't know why this happens, but it does (or did that time I wrote the last comment here).